# CreateProcessAsUser and createevent permissions

Tags: c++, winapi, winsock2

I'm creating an application which listens on a port, and when a client makes a request, it spawns a new process with a different user using LogonUser,CreateProcessAsUser .

I've setup 2 events with CreateEvent() function to signal the child that WSADuplicateSocket is ready to pass the SOCKADD_STORAGEW structure to the child process via a memory mapped file.

The OpenEvent() in the child process keep failing with error 5 (access denied ) when it is spawned from the application.

If I manually run a child/client using (shift + right click, run as) the OpenEvent function successfully manages to open the event.

The event is created in the global namespace (Global\myevent) and for testing purposes I have created a null Dacl ( i have verified permission on the Event with winobj )passed to the the CreateEvent() function.

I don't see what I'm missing .

here the concerned code snippet:

Server:

```
SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa;
CreateNullDacl(&sa);


if ((ghParentFileMappingEvent = CreateEvent(&sa, TRUE, FALSE, szParentEventName)) == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "CreateEvent() failed: %d\n", GetLastError());
    return false;
}

if ((ghChildFileMappingEvent = CreateEvent(&sa, TRUE, FALSE, szChildEventName)) == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "CreateEvent() failed: %d\n", GetLastError());
    CloseHandle(ghParentFileMappingEvent);
    return false;
}





PROCESS_INFORMATION pi = { 0 };
STARTUPINFO si = { 0 };
SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES procSa;
CreateNullDacl(&procSa);

HANDLE htok;
if (!LogonUser(chall->user, ".", chall->pass, LOGON32_LOGON_BATCH, LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, &htok)) {
    fprintf(stderr, "LogonUser() failed: %d\n", GetLastError());
    return false;

}


if(CreateProcessAsUser(htok, 0, szChildComandLineBuf, &procSa, 0, FALSE, NULL, NULL, "C:\\Users\\ch99", &si, &pi)) {
 //... 
}
```

CLient spawned from CreateProcessAsUser()

```
 if ((ghParentFileMappingEvent = OpenEventA(SYNCHRONIZE, FALSE, szParentEventName)) == 0)  // return 5 , access denied
{
    fprintf(fp, "OpenParentEvent failed: %d\n", GetLastError());
    return INVALID_SOCKET;
}

if ((ghChildFileMappingEvent = OpenEventA(SYNCHRONIZE, FALSE, szChildEventName)) == 0) { // return 5 access denied
    fprintf(fp, "OpenChildEvent failed: %d\n", GetLastError());
    CloseHandle(ghParentFileMappingEvent);
    ghParentFileMappingEvent = NULL;
    return INVALID_SOCKET;
}
```

Thanks for your reply.

Comment: A [mcve] would help clarify what you are asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After tried so many different thing, CreateEvent() keep returning access denied.

I have found a ugly workaround : in the SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES passed to CreateEvent() , i've set bInheritHandle to TRUE, and passed the handle value to the child process in argument .

At this point i'm able to use WaitForSingleObject() on the handle .

I'm realy curious to know why it didn't work as described in my first question...

Answer (score 0):

Based on document of [`CreateProcessAsUser`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessasusera):

> A handle to the **primary token** that represents a user. The handle must
>   have the **TOKEN_QUERY**, **TOKEN_DUPLICATE**, and **TOKEN_ASSIGN_PRIMARY** access
>   rights.

The following code works for me:

```
if (!OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(), TOKEN_QUERY | TOKEN_DUPLICATE | TOKEN_ASSIGN_PRIMARY, &htok))
    printf("OpenProcessToken() failed: %d\n", GetLastError());
if (!CreateProcessAsUser(htok, L"childProc.exe", NULL, NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi)) {
    printf("CreateProcessAsUser() failed: %d\n", GetLastError());
}
```

Or you can use [`CreateProcessWithToken`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-createprocesswithtokenw) instead (this require run as administrator):

```
HANDLE htok;
if (!LogonUser(L"userName", L"domain", L"password", LOGON32_LOGON_BATCH, LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, &htok)) {
    printf("LogonUser() failed: %d\n", GetLastError());
    return false;
}

if (!CreateProcessWithTokenW(htok, LOGON_WITH_PROFILE,L"childProc.exe", NULL, 0, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi)) {
    printf("CreateProcessAsUser() failed: %d\n", GetLastError());
}
```

With both above methods, **child process can open the event successfully**.

For your code I get error code 1314 (A required privilege is not held by the client.) when calling `CreateProcessAsUser`. Point out what am I missing and reproduce steps for your issue.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your time . If i use, CreateProcessWithTokenW() ( as admin or not ) it return 5 , access denied. If i run it with my attended user 'broker' it return 1314. I'm facing 1314 too with CreateProcessAsUser, btw after granting, SeAssignPrimaryTokenPrivilege, SeCreateTokenPrivilege and SeIncreaseQuotaPrivilege;  CreateProcessAsUser() sucess . I will try to run the server under local service account .